# Does a limit point always exist?

Tags: general-topology, limits

My instructor proves a statement during a lecture: if a set $E$ is open in a metric space $X$, then $E^c$ is closed.

In his proof, he writes: Suppose $E$ is open. We want to show that $E^c$ is closed (contains all its limit points). Let $x$ be a limit point of $E^c$. Then......

My question is how to know there exists a limit point in $E^c$? Thanks!

Comment: If there are no limit points, then $E^c$ contains all of its limit points. So the only interesting case is when $E^c$ has a limit point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Comment: In special case where $X$ is equipped with discrete distribution (and this space is metrizable) there are no limit points at all.

Comment: In fact, $E^c$ itself migh tbe empty

Comment: Do you want to know how he concluded that $E^c$ contains a limit point at all, or do you in general want to know why closed sets contain all their limit points? What is your definition of being closed? Also, what means "WTS"?

Comment: @M.Winter:  I think WTS stands for (we) Want To Show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct, but does not explicitly state the situation where the set of limit points is empty, starting off with such a limit point. A reformulation, just to make it clearer to the OP, would be  : Let $S$ be the set of limit points of $E^c$. We want to show that $S$ is a subset of $E^c$.

If $S$ is empty, then the empty set is contained in every set, so $S \subset E^c$ and $E^c$ contains all its limit points. (Stating the empty case explicitly)

If not, then let $x \in S$ be a limit point of $E^c$. Then , continue as in the stated proof.

So $x \in E^c$. Consequently $S \subset E^c$ and hence $E^c$ is closed.

Comment: There is no problem with the original proof. In the statement, "Let $x$ be a...", you do not need to know there are any such $x$'s when, as is the case here, you are proving a universal statement about such $x$'s.

Comment: @EricM.Schmidt Yes, you are right, and if you have downvoted, I understand that as well. I shall edit the answer.

Comment: I have rescinded the downvote.

Comment: @EricM.Schmidt Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that $(E^c)' \subseteq E^c$. Where for a set $A$, $A'$ denotes the set of its limit points.

To show an inclusion $A \subseteq B$, we usually let $x$ be an arbitary element of $A$ and show it must be in $B$. If there are no elements in $A$ this is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), so that's no problem.

So in the above vein we thus start by letting $x$ be an arbitrary point of $(E^c)'$. If there is no such point we're done anyway. ("nothing to be done")